# What type of parameters should I pass to this method

Tags: clojure, ring

I'm new to Clojure, and I am using `ring.velocity` to develop a webapp.

Here is my `ring.velocity.core/render` method:

```
(defn render
  [tname & kvs]
  "Render a template to string with vars:
    (render :name \"dennis\" :age 29)
   :name and :age are the variables in template.  "
  (let [kvs (apply hash-map kvs)]
    (render-template *velocity-render tname kvs)))
```

For this simple example, it works fine:

```
(velocity/render "test.vm" :name "nile")
```

But sometimes, we can't hard code the *key value* pairs. A common way:

```
(defn get-data [] {:key "value"}) ;; define a fn get-data dynamic.

(velocity/render "test.vm" (get-data));; **this go wrong** because in render fn , called (apply hash-map kvs)
```

Has the error:

```
No value supplied for key: ....
```

It looks like it is treated as if it was a single value. I've changed the type to `[]`, `{}`, and `()`, but each of these fails.

My question is: What does `& kvs` in clojure mean? How can I dynamically create it and pass it to method?

### ADD A Simple Test

```
(defn params-test [a & kvls]
   (println (apply hash-map kvls)))

(defn get-data []
   [:a "A"])

(defn test[]
   (params-test (get-data))
```

#### Result

```
 No value supplied for key:((:a "A"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to create a hash-map from a single list argument instead of list of arguments.

Use

```
(apply hash-map kvls)
```

instead of

```
(hash-map kvls)
```

In your original question you can try to use apply with partial

```
(apply (partial velocity/render "test.vm") (get-data))
```

Comment: thanks a log.  ```(apply (partial velocity/render "test.vm") (get-data)) ``` works fine.

Comment: `(apply hash-map kvls)` will _not_ work. `hash-map` does not take map entries in vector form. either `kvls` must be replaced with `(flatten kvls)` or the line must be replaced with `(into {} kvls)` because `into` uses `conj` which accepts map entries in vector form.

Comment: lgrapenthin, hash-map won't see a vector: apply will convert it to a parameters list. Try to execute it by yourself: `(apply hash-map [:a 1 :b 2])`